Is it possible to insert fields from a commit in the github pull_request_template?
When I create a PR, I first created a branch and committed changes.
With the commits I have fields such as:

a description (comment/message)
the commit UUID
the date / time when the commit happened
others...

My main problem, at the moment, is the comment from the first commit appears BEFORE the template. I'd like the message to appear after the # Description title. Something like this:
# Description

!comment

# Other things here

Is there anything in these templates, such as my "!comment" example, that would make it work?
I've checked the docs here but could not see anything about such, making me think it's not supported.
